# Complete list of facial shape keys to make?

Tags: rigging

I know how to make and use shape keys, but I'm having trouble coming up with all the keys I need for a complete face rig. Is there a checklist of all the shape keys needed to make a good rig?

Comment: I think Martin Z answered correctly, it really depends on what your face is supposed to do, actually it's your need that will determine your rigging, for example for a cartoonish character, maybe two bones will be enough for the lips... by the way maybe you should try bones rather than shapekeys, I would personally say that for this kind of rigging shapekeys are useful when it can fix what you were enable to do something with bones

Answer (score 1):

There is no checklist. It depends on what you do and what you need. You can rig things in different ways and may not even use shape keys at all or there can be hundreds of them. "Good" is a very abstract thing without any context. No matter what you do, the context of your situation should always dictate what you need. Just imagine how many different faces there can be in CG - aliens, animals, stylised faces, even inanimate objects can have faces in CG. Even if you are asking only about human faces they can vary greatly in detail, forms, age, artistic style and lots of other criteria and on top of that your animating needs may differ even more. There can be no checklist like you describe for all possible scenarios.

Comment: Okay, so what keys do you always make on every human face rig to get a good range of motion to allow a lot of flexibility in the animating process?

Comment: I don't think you will find a definite answer to this question nor that you should be looking for it. The problem is that every situation differs. It depends on what you need and what you do so just make what you need. Maybe reform the question to something like "What are the most common shapekeys to make when rigging a human face?" and provide more context about what it is for. However that will become opinion based then which is not perfect for Blender Stack Exchange. Maybe try Blenderartists.org forums as well and try to find some other people's rigs for examples.